# XMLException: Root element is missing

Tags: xml, msmq

Currently i've a windows service running that reads messages from a queue (MSMQ).
On receiveing a message from the queue, the following error is being thrown very very occassionally... (ie on running a test on 4000 transactions placed on a queue the exception was thrown twice... )

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this? Things worth noting are the queue is on a different server to where the application is running.

> 20121011161348.899 Job() -> Exception (XmlException) System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String res)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlReader.IsStartElement(String localname, String ns)    at
>   System.Messaging.XmlMessageFormatter.Read(Message message)    at
>   System.Messaging.Message.get_Body()    at
>   PTFMiddleware.Queues.QueueMessaging.Receive[T](MessageQueue queue,
>   String& label, Nullable`1 timeout)    at
>   PTFMiddleware.ProcessCCHMessages.Worker.Job()

Kind Regards,
Fiona

Answer (score 0):

Your service appears to be expecting XML data, and to be finding some data in the queue that isn't XML.  That much is clear from the error message you quote.  The root cause will be with the data producer; to identify the data producer you will need to identify the specific messages in the queue that are causing the problem.

In a test set of 4000 transactions, using a binary search technique will identify one of the problematic messages in as few as 14 test runs:

1. Set $low to 1, $high to 2000, $altlo to 2001, $althi to 4000.
2. Test the transactions from $low to $high.
3. If no error is reported (the problem is in the other half of the 
   data set), set $low to $altlo, $high to $althi.  If you're feeling paranoid and cautious, rerun the test to confirm that the error *does* occur in this set of data.
4. If $low = $high, the transaction in the position indicated is erroneous.
5. Set $althi to $high, $high to (($low + $high) / 2),  $altlo to $high + 1, $low to $low, and go to step 2.

Once you find the offending message(s), look to see where they are coming from and the nature of the problem.  Possibly there are multiple outermost elements in the XML being produced.  Possibly there is no containing element at all.  Find the broken data source; fix.